# Character writing in a array

Tags: c

I am using standard gcc compiler. I am trying to remove the spaces from the string. But I am getting following output. What is the problem here? It is working when i am doing out[s2+1] = '\0' but why not for in[s1+1] = '\0'. Please explain.

> OUTPUT:
>      After cutting s1: Ilikerambob
>      After cutting s2: rambolikeI

```
int check_anagrams(char *in,char *out)
{
int i=0;
int s1=0,s2=0;
while(in[i]!='\0')
{
    if(in[i]==' ')
    {
        i++;
        in[s1]=in[i];
    }
    in[s1]=in[i];
    i++;
    s1++;
}
in[s1+1]='\0';                         //Not working. Why?
printf("After cutting s1: %s\n",in);
i=0;
while(out[i]!='\0')
{
    if(out[i]==' ')
    {
        i++;
        out[s2]=out[i];
    }
    out[s2]=out[i];
    i++;
    s2++;
}
out[s2+1]='\0';                        //Working. Why?
printf("After cutting s2: %s\n",out);
}

int main()
{
char in[100]="I like rambo";
char out[100]="rambo like I";
int ans;
ans = check_anagrams(in,out);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line almost certainly does not do what you intend.

```
in[s1+1]='\0';
```

This will insert the string termination character `\0` at position `s1+1`, but because you have `s1++` in your loop, by the time this line is reached `s1` is already at the end of the string. Try replacing it with

```
in[s1] = '\0';
```

The `out` variable has the same problem, you just can't see it in the output because by sheer luck the extra character it's outputting is a space.

There is always danger in duplicating code. I would strongly recommend writing a separate `strip_spaces` routine and calling it twice rather than writing the same code twice.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void strip_spaces(char *str) {
  int ii = 0, jj = 0;
  while (str[ii]) {
    str[jj] = str[ii];
    if (str[ii++] != ' ')
      ++jj;
  }
  str[jj] = 0;
}

int check_anagrams(char *in,char *out) {
  strip_spaces(in);
  printf("After cutting s1: %s\n",in);
  strip_spaces(out);
  printf("After cutting s2: %s\n",out);
}

int main()
{
  char in[100]="I like rambo";
  char out[100]="rambo like I";
  int ans;
  ans = check_anagrams(in,out);
}
```

Comment: check the output carefully and the program also. It is working when i am doing out[s2+1] = '\0'

Comment: That's sheer luck. The second-to-last character in your `out` string is a space. Change the `%s` in your printfs to `[%s]` to be able to see the extra space at the end.

Comment: ok..I got it.Thanks for identifying the problem. Really helpful :)